# Issue with window.setinterval in IE11 (because of browser caching the JSON response)

Tags: javascript

I wrote a JavaScript method for loading contents on my page on an interval of one second. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer. The auto-reload after 1000ms does not work.

How to fix this?

```
function testing() {
    $.getJSON('test.php', function(data) {
        var lastresult = data.lastresult;
        $('#test').html(lastresult);
    }); 
}

// Execute testing() after every 1 second
window.setInterval(function(){testing()}, 1000);
```

---

**EDIT (I found the solution):** IE was caching the result of `test.php`, that's why it seemed to be not working for me. Adding this to the script worked:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Also, I tried below code, and they worked for me.

**Example 1 (worked):**

```
function testing() {
    $.getJSON('test.php', function(data) {
        var lastresult = data.lastresult;
        $('#test').html(lastresult);        
    }); 
}

testing(); // Worked!
```

**Example 2 (worked):**

```
function testing() {
    alert('test');
}

window.setInterval(function(){testing()}, 1000); // worked
```

Comment: Try it without `window` or try to do it without the function. You probably have a problem in the `testing` function because setInterval works fine for me in IE11.

Comment: What doesn't work? setInterval() or getJSON()?

Comment: I sense there would be issues with your `$.getJSON(` call which is preventing to execute

Comment: Hi, when I just put "testing();" in the script it works fine. The auto reload part is not working in IE. Sorry for being unclear.

Also functions not using Json work in IE using window.setinterval. Is seems to be a issue between IE and the combination of window.setinterval calling a function that uses getJSON.

Comment: IE caching was the problem. Adding "jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });" to the script fixed it.

Comment: I wouldn't call IE caching the "problem", it seems more likely that your server was not sending proper Cache-Control headers to prevent the client from caching...