# jquery - ajax - not loading a php file with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

The following code executes lastactivity.php every 10000 milliseconds on FireFox, Chrome, and Opera for Windows & Linux, but not Internet Explorer (tested on IE Version 11). The browser doesn't prompt me with any error codes so I have no other details to share. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm completely stumped. Thanks.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
$.get('lastactivity.php');
},10000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I thought I resolved the issue but the php file is not automatically loading every 10,000 milliseconds with IE.

Comment: I would make use of IE Development Tools (F12). Might help. Will also add more in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can separate the setInterval callback to it's own function. Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doGet(){
  $.get('lastactivity.php');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var refreshId = setInterval(doGet,10000);
});
</script>
```

See also: [window.setinterval not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987800/window-setinterval-not-working-in-ie11)

Comment: I'll give this a shot and upvote\accept if it resolves the issue. Hopefully this is applicable to all versions of IE. Thank you!

Comment: adding jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); before var refreshId resolved my issue